# State management with useContext and useReducer and fetching data with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

I have a React app that manages its global state with useContext and useReducer. My `BookList`component needs to fetch books from a server when it mounts. If fetching the books was successful they should be stored into global state.

My approach looks as follows

```
function BookList() {
    const [state, dispatch] = useContext(BookContext);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        BookService
            .fetchBooks()
            .then(resp => {
                setLoading(false);
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_BOOKS,
                    books: resp.data
                });
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {loading
                ? "Loading ..."
                : state.books.map(book => (
                    <div key={book.id}>{`${book.title} - $${book.price}`}</div>))
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

This works but produces the warning

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either ...

Do I have to add `dispatch` to the dependency array to ged rid of the warning or is there a better way?

Comment: Basicly yes, but the reference to this function won't change so it's optional actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is not very relevant here since the doc suggests omitting `dispatch` from the list of dependencies of `useEffect`, but you can safely put it in the dependency array because its identity is always stable.

the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) says:

> React guarantees that `dispatch` function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders.
> This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.